# sed (or awk) to sum values in a csv file

Tags: csv, sed, awk

I have a csv file where the lines look like this:

```
foo,bar,baz,5,6,8
zab,rab,oof,2,2,3
```

I need a command to transform it summing the last 3 values:

```
foo,bar,baz,19
zab,rab,oof,7
```

If possible I need a one liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for fixed length :

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4+$5+$6}' OFS=, file
```

And for not fixed length :

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<NF-2;i++)printf("%s,", $i)}{print $NF+$(NF-1)+$(NF-2)}' file
```

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not the right tool for arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F, -lane '$a+=$_ for(@F[3..5]);print join ",",@F[0..2],$a' your_file
```

small test below:

```
> echo "foo,bar,baz,5,6,8" | perl -F, -lane '$a+=$_ for(@F[3..5]);print join ",",@F[0..2],$a'
foo,bar,baz,19
```