# Editing a text file in linux using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have created a script that "simulates" a bank system that allows the user to check their balance and withdraw or deposit money depending on their needs. Details about customer, their balance etc. are saved in a text file named data.txt. When a customer withdraws or deposits money, the text file should be adjusted accordingly. Problem is, using sed like this

```
sed -i 's/$balance/$($balance + $depositval)/' data.txt
```

doesn't work. I tried with grep too but no luck either. Is there any way to change the customer's balance to a sum generated from their balance along with the amount of money they wish to deposit (or substract if they need to withdraw money) using sed and passing as argument a variable?

PS: Here are the contents of my data.txt file:

```
12345 Nick Abrams A 25575
67890 George Michaels I 10000
14680 Jack Jordan A 2960
13670 Michael Patton I 5065
```

The first field is the customer's card number. A and I indicate whether a customer's card is active or inactive. 5th field is balance. BTW i'm using bash shell. Depositval is read from keyboard using read command and balance is found from text file using grep.

For future reference, if somebody needs to do something similar i found out that my first attempt using sed like this

```
sed -i 's/$balance/$($balance + $depositval)/' data.txt
```

works too, just need to change the ' with "

Comment: `sed` does not know how to do arithmetic. And `bash` only deals with integers, not floats. I recommend you try using a programming language to write this program.

Comment: There is absolutely no support for arithmetic in `sed`. It's also not clear how you expect the values for the addition to be extracted. There is a weird hack in GNU `sed` which lets you run a shell command in the replacement part but you really should be looking at a different tool instead. Awk is popular for this sort of thing but you still have to work out how to tell Awk the input values (presumably by parsing the input line to figure out the previous value for *balance* and the value of *depositval).*

Comment: Vaguely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548771/sed-or-awk-to-sum-values-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You still have not told us how to conjure up a value for *depositval.*

Comment: @tripleee Updated my question. I hope I made it a little bit easier to understand what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you also have a customer name provided as input? Matching on the balance seems like a terrible idea, since you probably don't want to deposit on every account which has a specific balance but rather on a specific account (unless it is otherwise specified of course, an assignment could have such simplifications)

Comment: Requiring the customer's name to be exactly two tokens is an ugly constraint. For your amusement, read this. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: When script begins execution, it asks the user to enter their card number. After that using grep I print their data on screen (name and surname only, not card number or balance). Then I prompt them to check their balance, deposit or withdraw money. The rest (customer data, their balance etc. are found using grep)

Comment: Don't `grep` when you are ending up processing the entire file soon enough anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a text file rather than a database is hugely inefficient because the entire file has to be rewritten for each transaction.  But here are the beginnings of a solution.

```
awk -v deposit="123.45" -v account="14680" '$1 == account { $5 += deposit }' file >newfile &&
mv newfile file
```

GNU Awk has an option to rewrite the input file in-place so you don't have to do the manual moving of the new file back on top of the old one.

Comment: Nice. Does this work using variables in place of numbers? (i.e instead of using "123.45" i'd rather use "$balance").

Comment: Then do exactly that. (But here, the value we are passing in is the *depositval* not the *balance.* Awk will read and update the balance in one fell swoop. You can easily add a constraint like "back off with an error if the customer is withdrawing more than they have on their account, or if the account is inactive" but this comment field is not the full Awk Programming 101.)

Comment: Just for completeness, the stuff inside double quotes (but not the stuff inside single quotes, or even inside double quotes inside of a pair of single quotes) is the shell's domain, not Awk's.

Comment: Changing numbers with the desired variables worked. Thanks for helping me. Question answered.

Comment: @EdMorton My subconcious told me this is too much of a toy example to ever make it to anything like a system where this would actually matter but of course you are right. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test case. `$(( ... ))` arithmetic operation is specific to `bash`.

```
$ a=1
$ b=2
$ cat data.txt
name 1

$ sed "s/$a/$(( $a + $b ))/g" data.txt
name 3
```

Comment: I would imagine the OP imagines for the input values to come from the file which `sed` is currently processing, but without access to `data.txt` we are obviously speculating wildly here.

Comment: Correct, based on the speculation, I understand that OP knows `$balance` a priori and they are in OP's input file as digits.

Comment: I will edit my question and add my data.txt file if it is useful.

Comment: There is nothing which is specific to GNU `sed` here; this should be portable all the way back to the dark ages as far as `sed` is concerned; but arithmetic with `$(( ... ))` is a Bash-only feature so this will not work with some other shells.

Comment: Which (`bash`) is one of OP's tags and I had only tested `GNU sed` so far. Some people downvote with no mention of limitations, if any. Just being safe :-)